# Java check intersection of each element of ranges in a list

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, range

I have a list of objects representing a class of range , for example

```
public class Range
{
int upperValue;
int lowerValue
}
```

then i have

```
List<Range> ranges=new ArrayList<>();
```

after or while filling this list with values , i want to check for each new range inserted that if it intersects with previous values in the list.

so for example if i have

```
[1,4]
[2,4]
[3,5]
```

i want to detect that [3,5] intersects with [1,4] and [2,4]

and that [2,4] intersects with [1,4]

so what i managed to do but was not efficient is:

first i sort the list by lower values using a compartor.

then i loop into the list again after being sorted and check starting from the second element in the list whether it intersects with all previous elements in the list , by for example looping in a reverse manner.

something like this

```
Map<Range,List<Range>> rangeIntersectionMap=new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<ranges.size();i++)
{
if(i>0)
{
List<Range> intersections= rangeIntersectionMap.get(ranges.get(i));
if(intersections==null)
intersections=new ArrayList<>();
for(int j=i-1;j>0;j--)
{
if(checkIntersection(ranges.get(i),ranges.get(j))
{
intersections.add(ranges.get(j));
}
}
rangeIntersectionMap.put(ranges.get(i),intersections);
}
}
```

this means probably that if i have an list of 20 elements that i have a factorial time complexity to check what elements intersect with each other.

i think a NavigableMap might solve this , however i could not use it correctly for this purpose.

Any other data structure or algorithm suggested ?

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by intersection? "[3,5] intersects with [1,4] and [2,4]".

Comment: Hint: formatting matters. You want us to spend our time to help, but you dont have the 1 minute to properly indent your source code?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Interval Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) structure for these kinds of problems.

The idea is:

- Each node represents interval, save both endpoints in a node
- Save max (right) endpoint value of it's subtree in each node
- Key for search is smaller value of the two

Inserting:

- use low value to navigate inserts
- update max values in subtrees accordingly

Searching:

- if interval in a node intersects query interval, return it
- else if left subtree is null, go right
- else if max value in left subtree is less than searched low value, go right
- else go left

You can check this [video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/lecture/ot9vw/interval-search-trees) and [implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/93intersection/IntervalST.java.html) by Proffesor Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IntervalTree`.

```
/**
 * @param <T> - The type stored in the tree -
 *            must implement IntervalTree.Interval but beyond that you can do what you like.
 *            Probably store that value in there too.
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 */
public class IntervalTree<T extends IntervalTree.Interval> {
    // My intervals.
    private final List<T> intervals;
    // My center value. All my intervals contain this center.
    private final long center;
    // My interval range.
    private final long lBound;
    private final long uBound;
    // My left tree. All intervals that end below my center.
    private final IntervalTree<T> left;
    // My right tree. All intervals that start above my center.
    private final IntervalTree<T> right;

    public IntervalTree(List<T> intervals) {
        if (intervals == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        // Initially, my root contains all intervals.
        this.intervals = intervals;

        // Find my center.
        center = findCenter();

    /*
     * Builds lefts out of all intervals that end below my center.
     * Builds rights out of all intervals that start above my center.
     * What remains contains all the intervals that contain my center.
     */
        // Lefts contains all intervals that end below my center point.
        final List<T> lefts = new ArrayList<>();
        // Rights contains all intervals that start above my center point.
        final List<T> rights = new ArrayList<>();

        // Track my bounds while distributing.
        long uB = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        long lB = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        for (T i : intervals) {
            long start = i.getStart();
            long end = i.getEnd();
            if (end < center) {
                // It ends below me - move it to my left.
                lefts.add(i);
            } else if (start > center) {
                // It starts above me - move it to my right.
                rights.add(i);
            } else {
                // One of mine.
                lB = Math.min(lB, start);
                uB = Math.max(uB, end);
            }
        }

        // Remove all those not mine.
        intervals.removeAll(lefts);
        intervals.removeAll(rights);
        // Record my bounds.
        uBound = uB;
        lBound = lB;

        // Build the subtrees.
        left = lefts.size() > 0 ? new IntervalTree<>(lefts) : null;
        right = rights.size() > 0 ? new IntervalTree<>(rights) : null;

    /*
     * @todo: Build my ascending and descending arrays.
     */
    }

    /*
     * Returns a list of all intervals containing the point.
     */
    public List<T> query(long point) {
        // Check my range.
        if (point >= lBound) {
            if (point <= uBound) {
                // In my range but remember, there may also be contributors from left or right.
                List<T> found = new ArrayList<>();
                // Gather all intersecting ones.
                // Could be made faster (perhaps) by holding two sorted lists by start and end.
                for (T i : intervals) {
                    if (i.getStart() <= point && point <= i.getEnd()) {
                        found.add(i);
                    }
                }

                // Gather others.
                if (point < center && left != null) {
                    found.addAll(left.query(point));
                }
                if (point > center && right != null) {
                    found.addAll(right.query(point));
                }

                return found;
            } else {
                // To right.
                return right != null ? right.query(point) : Collections.<T>emptyList();
            }
        } else {
            // To left.
            return left != null ? left.query(point) : Collections.<T>emptyList();
        }

    }

    private long findCenter() {
        //return average();
        return median();
    }

    protected long median() {
        // Choose the median of all centers. Could choose just ends etc or anything.
        long[] points = new long[intervals.size()];
        int x = 0;
        for (T i : intervals) {
            // Take the mid point.
            points[x++] = (i.getStart() + i.getEnd()) / 2;
        }
        Arrays.sort(points);
        return points[points.length / 2];
    }

    /*
     * What an interval looks like.
     */
    public interface Interval {
        public long getStart();

        public long getEnd();

    }

    /*
     * A simple implemementation of an interval.
     */
    public static class SimpleInterval implements Interval {
        private final long start;
        private final long end;

        public SimpleInterval(long start, long end) {
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }

        @Override
        public long getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        @Override
        public long getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" + start + "," + end + "}";
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make some test data.
        final int testEntries = 1 * 100;
        ArrayList<SimpleInterval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < testEntries; i++) {
            // Make a random interval.
            long start = random.nextLong();
            intervals.add(new SimpleInterval(start, start + 1000));
        }
        ProcessTimer timer = new ProcessTimer();
        IntervalTree<SimpleInterval> tree = new IntervalTree<>(intervals);
        System.out.println("Took " + timer);
    }

}
```

You can now use the `query` method to serach for intervals that include any particular value.

Comment: And then people say "stackoverflow isnt a free code writing service" ...